# Visual Studio 2008 cl.exe properties openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

I need set property for compiler cl.exe /openmp on.

Tell me please, how and where can I do this?

Comment: There is a link on this page... http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/

Comment: Project properties -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Language`. Set `Open MP Support` to `Yes (/openmp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to set this for a Visual Studio C++ project: See e.g. [this article in the knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311065/en-us).

[image]

Comment: And if you select `Language` instead of `Command Line` there is the `Open MP Support` drop-down list. <rant>Microsoft cannot even get the OpenMP name right (there is no space between Open and MP), not to mention their crappy implementation which stalled somewhere in 2002 (MSVC++ only supports OpenMP 2.0)</rant>.